Proper approach to finding solutions to equation involving damped exponential sum
I'm a neuroscientist, not a mathematician. I have the following equation:
$$
\frac{2}{n} - \frac{4 (n-1)}{n} \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \exp \left(-4 \pi ^2 k^2 w^2\right) = 0
$$
I would like to do two things:
First, I'd like to learn what mathematical techniques are used to find approximate solutions for $w$ given positive integer $n$. I can easily use Wolfram Mathematica to find solutions, but I'd like to know about the general mathematical approach.
Second, I don't understand how one goes about answering the following question: as $n \rightarrow \infty$, does $w \rightarrow \infty$, and if so, with what kind of relationship between $n$ and $w$?

Denoting $\theta(w)=\sum _{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{-4 \pi ^2 k^2 w^2}$ and supposing $n\neq 0$, from your equation follows
$$\theta(w)=\frac n{n-1}$$
For $n\gg1$
$$1+\frac1n\approx1+2e^{-4\pi^2 w^2},\Rightarrow,w\approx\frac{\sqrt{\ln(2n)}}{2\pi}$$
what works fine already at small $n,(\sim 4)$. For the numeric check you can use the figures from the solution by @Mariusz Iwaniuk

$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \exp \left(-4 \pi ^2 k^2 w^2\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(-1+\vartheta _3\left(0,e^{-4 \pi ^2 w^2}\right)\right)$$
where: $\vartheta _3$ is theta function.
Mathematica code can be executed for free here, you must only Sign In:
f[n_, w_] := 2/n - (4 n - 1)/n*1/2 (-1 + EllipticTheta[3, 0, E^(-4 \[Pi]^2 w^2)]);
Grid[Join[{{"Positive Integer", "First solution", "Second solution"}},
Table[{n, (w /. FindRoot[f[n, w] == 0, {w, #}] & /@ {-1/2, 
    1/2})[[1]], (w /. FindRoot[f[n, w] == 0, {w, #}] & /@ {-1/2, 
    1/2})[[2]]}, {n, 1, 20}]], Frame -> All]
ContourPlot[f[n, w] == 0, {n, 0, Infinity}, {w, -1/2, 1/2}, FrameLabel -> {n, w}]


FindRoot uses a methods to approximate solution you can find here.

Let
$$w=\pm\frac{1}{2 \pi }\sqrt{\log\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}$$ and, for a given $p$, we want to solve for $t$ the equation
$$f_p=\sum_{k=1}^p t^{k^2}-a \qquad \text{with} \qquad  a=\frac{1}{2 (n-1)}$$
Suppose that we consider that $\sum_{k=1}^p t^{k^2}$ is a series expansion to $O\left(t^{(k+1)^2}\right) $; then, use power series reversion.
For example, for $p=3$, this would give
$$t=a-a^4+4 a^7-a^9-22 a^{10}+13 a^{12}+140
   a^{13}-136a^{15}+O\left(a^{16}\right)$$ For $n=11$ This would give
$$t_{3}=\frac{204774412783219983}{4096000000000000000}$$ to which corresponds
$$w_{3}= \color{red}{\pm 0.27547404571328139}38$$
If you use $p=4$, you should obtain
$$w_{4}= \color{red}{\pm 0.2754740457132813951449464724}62$$
Using the infinite sum, that is to say solving
$$\vartheta _3\left(0,e^{-4 \pi ^2 w^2}\right)=\frac n{n-1}$$ the exact solution, as already given by @Mariusz Iwaniuk, would be
$$w=\pm 0.275474045713281395144946472479\cdots$$
Edit
Another which could be done is to take logarithms and solve for $t$
$$\log (\vartheta _3(0,t))=b\qquad \text{with} \qquad  b=\log \left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)$$
Instead of Taylor series, build the $[k,k]$ Padé approximant of the lhs such as
$$P_2=\frac{6 t (2 t-1)}{7 t^2+3 t-3}$$
$$P_3=\frac{2 t \left(721 t^2-750 t+615\right)}{3
   \left(187 t^3-78 t^2-45 t+205\right)}$$ whose respective errors are $\frac{82 }{45}t^5$ and $\frac{958 }{7175}t^7$.
So, at the price of a quadratic or cubic equations in $t$, you should have some reasonable estimates.
Again, for $n=11$, $P_2$ would lead to
$$w_{(2)}= \color{red}{\pm 0.275474}35$$
and $P_3$ would lead to
$$w_{(3)}=\color{red}{\pm 0.275474045}64$$
If $P_2$ looks sufficient to you, then
$$w_{(2)} \sim \frac 1{2\pi} \sqrt{\log\Bigg(\frac{2 (7 b-12) }{-3 (b+2)+\sqrt{3 \left(31 b^2-36 b+12\right) } } \Bigg)   }$$
From here, an asymptotics for large $n$ is
$$w_{(2)} \sim   \frac {\sqrt{\log (2 n)}}{2\pi}\Big(1-\frac{1}{2 n \log (2 n)}+\cdots  \Big)$$
Update
$P_3$ being a very good approximation of $\log (\vartheta _3(0,t))$,we can solve exactly the corresponding cubic equation in $t$ (using the hyperbolic solution) and expand the result as a series around $b=0$. As a result
$$t=\frac 12 b+\frac 14 b^2+\frac 1{12} b^3-\frac 1{24} b^4-\frac {29}{240} b^5-\frac {97}{720} b^6+O(b^7)$$
For $n=11$, the above gives $t=\color{red}{\pm 0.04999375}79$
Injected in the equation
$$\log (\vartheta _3(0,t))-b=\frac{367}{2520}b^7$$ which is not very large since $b\sim \frac 1n$.
Then
$$\log \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)=\log
   \left(\frac{2}{b}\right)-\frac{b}{2}
   -\frac{b^2}{24}+\frac{b^3}{8}+O\left
   (b^4\right)$$ or, in terms of $n$
$$w=\frac {\sqrt{\log (2 n)}}{2\pi}\Bigg(1-\frac{1}{2 n \log (2 n)}-\frac{2 \log (2 n)+1}{8 n^2 \log ^2(2n)}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3 \log ^3(2n)}\right) \Bigg)$$
